# What exactly does "next" mean in package.json dependencies?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

What exactly does **next** mean in package.json dependencies?

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^15.4.2",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-router-dom": "next"
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The next tag is used by some projects to identify the upcoming version.By default, other than latest, no tag has any special significance to npm itself.
>
> [NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag)

Answer (score 26):

Specifically, and according to the documentation I found this helpful:

> By default, the latest tag is used by npm to identify the current
>   version of a package, and npm install  (without any @ or
>   @ specifier) installs the latest tag. **Typically, projects only
>   use the "latest" tag for stable release versions, and use other tags for
>   unstable versions such as prereleases**.
>
> The next tag is used by some projects to identify the upcoming
>   version.
>
> By default, other than latest, no tag has any special significance to
>   npm itself.

So, for instance, I had some issues related to npm itself generating npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied errors on package installations, that I first corrected by reverting to an earlier version of npm (from 5.4.0):

```
npm install -g npm@5.3.0
```

But npm is also one of those packages that *does* use the "next" tag in their distribution, so to take advantage of that in the newest but not officially "stable version", you could also run:

```
npm install -g npm@next
```

Which installed 5.5.1

Running: `npm show npm versions --json`shows the following version history to give an idea what exactly was installed:
[ ...
  "5.3.0",
  "5.4.0",
  "5.4.1",
  "5.4.2",
  "5.5.0",
  "5.5.1"
]

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is an attempt to state the purpose of `@next` more simply. The language in the docs and in other answers appears overly complex.*

Using `next` as the version number will allow a pre-release version if the project has one available. It will otherwise allow the latest stable version.