# What is the difference between typescript@latest and typescript@next NPM pckages?

Tags: typescript, npm

How does `typescript@next` differ from `typescript@latest`?
It's clear to me what `typescript@next` does, but the problem I have had is knowing what the difference is from `typescript@latest`. As far as I could tell, they are the same thing. [What exactly does "next" mean in package.json dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182463/what-exactly-does-next-mean-in-package-json-dependencies) has been proposed as a possible answer, but it only references `typescript@next`, which doesn't explain to me how the two very from each other.

I would like to know, if they install different versions, or are they basically the same thing? And if they are different, why would someone use one over the other?

Comment: That's the **same package**, just different _tags_. See the versions tab on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript (right now latest is 4.5.4 and next is 4.6.0-dev-20220110).

Comment: @Jonsharpe that's not a dup buddy. At 104k you should know that... Seems like everywhere I go your following me, almost as if you have been watching my profile. Kinda creepy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does "next" mean in package.json dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182463/what-exactly-does-next-mean-in-package-json-dependencies)

Comment: Yes it is, the answers explain what those tags mean. If you mean it doesn't address typescript specifically, then I'd note that we probably don't want one Q&A pair for every package on NPM that uses tags.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you were right on the other answer, so let me take a look. If your right Ill dup it.

Comment: @jonsharpe so here's the deal. I didn't understand the difference between the two, and the question doesn't ask what the difference is. So when it is queried as such, it doesn't pop up. In fairness, I shouldn't have selected jsejcksn's answer because he doesn't explain the difference between the two. If you agree, I will deselect his answer. If you don't agree, let me know why, so we can bring resolve to the issue.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's a meaningful difference between how tags generally work in NPM packages, and what they mean to Typescript specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Jon has provided some useful links in his comments: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659701/what-is-the-difference-between-typescriptlatest-and-typescriptnext-npm-pckages#comment124911855_70659701), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70659701/what-is-the-difference-between-typescriptlatest-and-typescriptnext-npm-pckages#comment124911929_70659701).

In the specific case of TypeScript, the `next` tag refers to an **unstable** version of TypeScript which is [self-described](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/nightly-builds.html) as a ["nightly"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56490/what-does-nightly-builds-mean) release. It includes access to upcoming (and potentially buggy or incomplete) features which aren't ready for the stable release.

And the NPM package `typescript@latest` will install the most current stable version of TypeScript.

At the time of writing `typescript@latest` installs TypeScript v4.5.x and `typescript@next` installs TypeScript v4.6.x. Version 4.5 is the current stable version and 4.6 is the version being worked on, but it's not considered stable yet and shouldn't be used in production.

Comment: I edited your answer to reference `typescript@latest`, just because Jon tagged it as a dup because another question already explains what `typescript@next` is, however that's not what the question above asks, it asks what the difference between `typescript@latest` and `typescript@next` is, and I just wanted your answer to reflect that. I figured out what the difference was on my own so your answer was good enough for me, I just wanted to make sure it was good enough for everyone else too.